# Converting image files to VARBINARY(max) in flutter

Tags: sql, sql-server, image, flutter, varbinary

I need to store images that are captured using "image picker" in a SQL server database

```
final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 25);
```

now, I know that the images should be stored in a "VARBINARY" datatype. I tried to convert the XFile "image" that I got from the "ImagePicker()" to VARBINARY and these are the steps I made.

```
final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 25);

var imageTemp = File(image.path);
```

and then I store the image in the database using the following.

```
Attachment(
            attachmentData: base64Encode((imageTemp .readAsBytesSync())),
            attachmentName: imageTemp .path.split('/').last,
            attachmentSize: imageTemp .readAsBytesSync().lengthInBytes,
            attachmentType: imageTemp .path.split(".").last,
          )
```

"attachmentData: base64Encode((imageTemp .readAsBytesSync()))"
"attachmentData is a String"
So from XFile to VARBINARY, I had done the following

```
 final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 25);
 var imageTemp = File(image.path);

  base64Encode((imageTemp .readAsBytesSync())) //the sent data
```

when I print the data after the readAsByteSynce() it starts with **[255,216,.255,..]** which is  FF D8 FF
it looks like this
[screen shot of print(imageTemp.readAsBytesSync())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPQXl.png)

and when I print the image after using base64Encode it starts with **/9j/4Q**
it looks like this
[screen shot of print(base64Encode((imageTemp.readAsBytesSync())))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7StW6.png)

now when it's stored in the SQL server database it starts with **0x2F39**
it looks like this [screen shot of the attachmebtData field in the SQL server database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES5aZ.png)

The image extension is .jpg. Shouldn't jpg images start with **0xFF**?
I need to take these images and view them in ArcGIS and when I open the image it says that the images are not in a supported format.

can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong and why are my jpg images starts with 0x2F in the database and not 0xFFD8FF and how to fix this?
I want the image to be stored in the database

I also Tried converting Uint8List to hex using dart package **hex 0.2.0**
which converted it to this [the output of print(Hex.encode(await image.readAsBytes))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIUgR.png)

as you can see in the above picture it starts with **ffd8ff** which is the correct format for jpg pictures, but when I send this to the database it looks like it converts these letters to VARBINARY and the output starts with **0x666666** and looks like this [image from SQL server AttachmentData field when Hex.encode data was sent to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BFoj.png)

Comment: `0x2F39` are the bytes for characters `/9`. You're base64Encode-ing the image data bytes to send it - but where are you base64Decode-ing it before inserting into the database?

Comment: Dude, the problem was me not decoding it. after your comment and I to the API and decoded it before inserting it into the database. thanks a lot. 
I'm using python, and this is what I did.
"attachment.attachmentData = base64.decodebytes(attachment.attachmentData)"

Can you please add your comment as an answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I'm not decoding it in the backend before inserting it into the database.

I'm Using Python "FAST API" and I needed to write the following line to **attachmentdata** before inserting it into the database.

```
attachment.attachmentData = base64.decodebytes(attachment.attachmentData)
```